# Conversion of Dec to Hex in C# script

Tags: hex, type-conversion, decimal

Trying to take a decimal value and convert it to hex. This is a C# script inside SCADA program. Following converts Hex to Dec just fine:

```
using System;
using MasterSCADA.Script.FB;
using MasterSCADA.Hlp;
using FB;
using System.Linq;

public partial class ФБ : ScriptBase
{
    public override void Execute()
    {
    string hexValue = InVal;
    int num = Int32.Parse(hexValue, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
    OutVal = num;   
    }
}
```

But I am having problem with the opposite - when I try to convert Dec to Hex. To my understanding the following should work but it gives an error: No overload for method 'ToString' takes '1' arguments in line 12

```
11    int? decValue = InVal;
12        string hexValue = decValue.ToString("X");
13        //string hexValue = string.Format("{0:F0}", decValue);
14        uint num = uint.Parse(hexValue, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
15        OutVal = num;
```

I can avoid the error by using line 13 instead of 12 but in this case I am converting Hex to Dec instead of Dec to Hex. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to call `ToString(string)` on an `int?` value. `Nullable<T>` doesn't have a `ToString(string)` overload. You need something like:

```
string hexValue = decValue == null ? "" : decValue.Value.ToString("X");
```

(Obviously adjust the above depending on what you want the result to be if `decValue` is null.)

Comment: Thanks! Tried your solution. Compiles without errors but returns same decimal value. No conversion.

Comment: @user2087438: Then something else must be wrong - because it *definitely* converts to hex. Try using `int? decVal = 255;` for example - `hexValue` will be "FF".

Comment: Thanks for help! Stupid me. I was reading the wrong variable. OutVal = hexValue solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try `decValue.Value.ToString("X");`
Your type is `int?` and not `int`

Comment: Same - compiles good but returns decimal value without conversion - what I enter to inVal I get in OutVal.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my function:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
class DecimalToHexadecimal
{

    static string DecToHex(decimal decim)
    {
        string result = String.Empty;

        decimal dec = decim;

        while (dec >= 1)
        {
            var remainer = dec % 16;
            dec /= 16;
            result = ((int)remainer).ToString("X") + result;
        }

        return result;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter decimal");
        decimal dec = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Hexadecimal representation to {0} is {1}", dec, DecToHex(dec));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```